# How to do a Django subquery

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql

I have two examples of code which accomplish the same thing. One is using python, the other is in SQL.

Exhibit A (Python):

```
surveys = Survey.objects.all()
consumer = Consumer.objects.get(pk=24)

for ballot in consumer.ballot_set.all()
    consumer_ballot_list.append(ballot.question_id)

for survey in surveys:
    if survey.id not in consumer_ballot_list:
        consumer_survey_list.append(survey.id)
```

Exhibit B (SQL):

```
SELECT * FROM clients_survey WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT question_id FROM consumers_ballot WHERE consumer_id=24) ORDER BY id;
```

I want to know how I can make exhibit A much cleaner and more efficient using Django's ORM and subqueries.

In this example:
I have ballots which contain a question_id that refers to the survey which a consumer has answered.

I want to find all of the surveys that the consumer hasn't answered. So I need to check each question_id(survey.id) in the consumer's set of ballots  against the survey model's id's and make sure that only the surveys that the consumer does NOT have a ballot of are returned.

Comment: If your code works fine and you just want to improve it, then maybe you should go to a website, where they help to review your code, instead of SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You more or less have the correct idea. To replicate your SQL code using Django's ORM you just have to break the SQL into each discrete part:

1.create table of question_ids the consumer 24 has answered

2.filter the survey for all ids not in the aformentioned table

```
consumer = Consumer.objects.get(pk=24)
# step 1
answered_survey_ids = consumer.ballot_set.values_list('question_id', flat=True) 
# step 2
unanswered_surveys_ids = Survey.objects.exclude(id__in=answered_survey_ids).values_list('id', flat=True)
```

This is basically what you did in your current python based approach except I just took advantage of a few of Django's nice ORM features.

- [`.values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) - this allows you to extract a specific field from all the objects in the given queryset.
- [`.exclude()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) - this is the opposite of `.filter()` and returns all items in the queryset that don't match the condition.
- [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) - this is useful if we have a list of values and we want to filter/exclude all items that match those values.

Hope this helps!